# how to configure environment file if insert data from flink sql client to hive?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

**My Environment:**

| component | version |
| --- | --- |
| Hadoop | 3.1.2 |
| Hive | 2.3.4 |
| Flink | 1.12.0 |
| Ubuntu | 20.04 |

I'm new to Flink SQL Client

My $FLINK_HOME/conf/`flink-hive.yaml` is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pZ2YkrSVrx/)
It's OK for many `FLINK SQL Client commands`,
but when I do the following:

Flink SQL> `INSERT into code_city values(1,'a','b','2017-09-15');`
I got:

```
[INFO] Submitting SQL update statement to the cluster...
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector
```

**Problem:**

How to configure above `flink-hive.yaml`
if I want to `insert data from FLINK SQL CLient into Hive Table`?

The Official Example .yaml is [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/hive/hive_catalog.html) but it's not complete,

Thanks for your help~!

Answer (score 0):

There's no `flink-hive.yaml` AFAK, you should config the catalog properties in `sql-client-defaults.yaml`.

And then you need to config your `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment parameter so that Flink can load Hadoop related jars.

Finally you need add necessary hive connector dependency and hive dependency in your `Flink/lib`, for example:

- flink-sql-connector-hive-2.3.6_2.11-1.12.0.jar
- hive-exec-2.3.2.jar

these jar can download from Apache Flink website.

After these steps, you can enjoy Flink + hive